# How could I prevent Bouncycastle being added as a JCE provider?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, jce

I've spent 2 days chasing a strange SSL problem with Tomcat (bad record mac) and I finally found it was caused by Bouncycastle JCE Provider implementation.

This is maybe the third time I had this kind of weird, strange behavior problems (Others being problems reloading webapps, or reading certificate info).

I believe Bouncycastle is a great library, but the fact that it is commonly added as a global provider for the Java process with `Security.addProvider()`, and that third party libraries do this internally and without warning, makes it a big problem. [Example](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.ws/com.springsource.org.apache.ws.security/1.5.8/org/apache/ws/security/WSSConfig.java#WSSConfig.0addJceProviders)

**So, is there a way to prevent BC from being added as a security provider, globally?** 
I've tried to use a Security Manager directly and through Tomcat, but I couldn't make it work, and I don't know how could I disable only that action. (I don't want any other change in my system)

My code uses the library but it never needs to add it as a JCE provider. 
I can't  understand why the JCE API works that way and creates such a big point of instability, but maybe that's another question.

Comment: Are you sure it is added via `addProvider()`? If I understand the JavaDoc right usually this should add BC provider at the end of the list (lowest priority).

Comment: @Robert: Well, I don't know exactly how the precedence rules work, but the fact is that the BC implementation is picked and used, at least in the SSL engine and in keystore management. 
But you're right, my question applies for the other registration methods, like `insertAt`, too.

Comment: @Robert: In my current issue, the [culprit code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.ws/com.springsource.org.apache.ws.security/1.5.8/org/apache/ws/security/WSSConfig.java#WSSConfig.loadProvider%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29) tries to install the provider right after the SUN provider, or in position 2 as a callback ...

Comment: The Sun JCA defines multiple providers (see file `lib7security/java.security`). On my system the first 10 providers are from sun. IMHO you should file this as bug of the apache.ws.security module. You don't have to install a SecurityProvider system wide to use it. Just reference the instance, e.g. [Cipher.getInstance(String transformation,
                 Provider provider)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#getInstance(java.lang.String,%20java.security.Provider))

Comment: So the answer is no, you cannot stop this behavior. Every registered provider is globally available. I would be curious to know why the BC provider should cause a bad record mac, and how you were able to work around the issue.

Comment: Hi @JamesKPolk. Sadly, I didn't have the time to analyze the bad mac problem. SSL protocol issues are really hard... My workaround was to use Tomcat 8.5 and the mixed NioProtocol, wich uses the Java API but delegates to a native OpenSSL the SSL handling. But now we see strange spikes in Tomcat process CPU related to NioBlockingSelector... Sometimes I hate computers